# How can I divide sub-selections of a data frame by another data frame using minimal memory usage in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with many columns and I want to divide it by another data frame at regular column intervals with minimal memory usage.

For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1], [2,4,3,1,6,5,7,8,9,4]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,3],[7,6],[9,3]])
```

I want to divide df1 by df2 multiple times at every two column interval. The result I would want is:

```
finalDf = pd.DataFrame([[1/1,2/3,3/1,4/3,5/1,6/3,7/1,8/3,9/1,10/3], [10/7,9/6,8/7,7/6,6/7,5/6,4/7,3/6,2/7,1/6], [2/9,4/3,3/9,1/3,6/9,5/3,7/9,8/3,9/9,4/3]])
```

I think the code would look something like this:

```
df3 = df1.iloc[:, 0:2].divide(df2.iloc[:,:].values, axis = 'rows')
df4 = df1.iloc[:, 2:4].divide(df2.iloc[:,:].values, axis = 'rows')
df5 = df1.iloc[:, 4:6].divide(df2.iloc[:,:].values, axis = 'rows')
df6 = df1.iloc[:, 6:8].divide(df2.iloc[:,:].values, axis = 'rows')
finalDf = pd.concat([df3, df4, df5, df6], axis=1)
```

The only way I can think to implement something like that would be to put it in a loop, but I feel like that is not the smart way to do it.  Is there a way to vectorize the solution?

Answer (score 2):

#### Using `pd.concat`:

```
res = pd.concat([df2]*5, 1)
res.columns = df1.columns

df1/res
```

```
          0         1         2         3    ...            6         7         8         9
0  1.000000  0.666667  3.000000  1.333333    ...     7.000000  2.666667  9.000000  3.333333
1  1.428571  1.500000  1.142857  1.166667    ...     0.571429  0.500000  0.285714  0.166667
2  0.222222  1.333333  0.333333  0.333333    ...     0.777778  2.666667  1.000000  1.333333
```

To generalize:

```
res = pd.concat([df2]*(df1.shape[1]//df2.shape[1]), 1)
```

Comment: I might be doing something wrong here, but I don't get the same result? 
final = df1/pd.concat([df2]*5, 1)
final

 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 0.666667 0.666667 0.666667 0.666667 0.666667 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1 1.428571 1.428571 1.428571 1.428571 1.428571 1.500000 1.500000 1.500000 1.500000 1.500000 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2 0.222222 0.222222 0.222222 0.222222 0.222222 1.333333 1.333333 1.333333 1.333333 1.333333 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

That didn't turn out very pretty.. but does that provide any hints?

Comment: I had an error, I wasn't changing column names in my answer, try it now

Comment: Awesome! The first section did the trick. I think there is a syntax problem with the general solution, but the first part does the trick. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm off my game today, try the general solution now, since that one is more useful than a hardcoded one :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the columns are numeric, you can trick pandas into performing indexed aligned division by relabelling `df1`'s columns to mimic `df2`'s.

```
df1.columns = np.tile(df2.columns, df1.shape[1] // df2.shape[1])
# A little more trickery to restore the ordering later.
ordering = df1.columns.values.argsort(kind='mergesort').argsort()

print (df1)
    0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0   1
0   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
1  10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2   1
2   2  4  3  1  6  5  7  8  9   4

print (df2)
   0  1
0  1  3
1  7  6
2  9  3
```

```
result = df1.div(df2).iloc[:, ordering]
```

This does not generate any extra data.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot to mention that I'd like to keep the columns ordered. Does this trick result in a faster execution compared with the other? Thanks so much!

Comment: @aday I fixed the ordering. Also, I think it should because this does not generate any extra data like `pd.concat` would do.

Comment: No point in readding it my answer now, but `df1/np.tile(df2, 5)` may beat both of these

Comment: @user3483203 Possibly, but the question puts a constraint on memory, not performance... `tile` may be good but it certainly duplicates the data ;)

Answer (score 1):

#### Everything in place

```
for c in df1:
  df1[c] /= df2[c % 2].values  # added .values to try and quicken it up a bit

df1.round(4)

        0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
0  1.0000  0.6667  3.0000  1.3333  5.0000  2.0000  7.0000  2.6667  9.0000  3.3333
1  1.4286  1.5000  1.1429  1.1667  0.8571  0.8333  0.5714  0.5000  0.2857  0.1667
2  0.2222  1.3333  0.3333  0.3333  0.6667  1.6667  0.7778  2.6667  1.0000  1.3333
```

---

#### Independent of columns names

```
from itertools import cycle

for i, j in zip(df1, cycle(df2)):
  df1[i] /= df2[j].values

df1.round(4)

        0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
0  1.0000  0.6667  3.0000  1.3333  5.0000  2.0000  7.0000  2.6667  9.0000  3.3333
1  1.4286  1.5000  1.1429  1.1667  0.8571  0.8333  0.5714  0.5000  0.2857  0.1667
2  0.2222  1.3333  0.3333  0.3333  0.6667  1.6667  0.7778  2.6667  1.0000  1.3333
```

Comment: Does this have an advantage over the others in terms of memory usage? The others look like it needs to make one copy of the data frame, no?

Comment: Yes, "In place" means modify existing dataframe.  Should not need to create any copies.

Comment: So many great solutions! All better than mine. :) Thanks so much!